# Formation of traveling waves

Tags: waves

can a traveling wave exist on a closed cylindrical string? or more general, what are the conditions for the formation of traveling waves vs the conditions for the formation of standing waves?

Comment: Wavelength multiple of string length now go do your own homework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to form travelling waves on a closed string:

[image]

In general, whenever you can form travelling waves, you can always superpose waves going in opposite directions to make a standing wave. Some systems, on the other hand, to not admit travelling waves, such as systems with fixed boundary conditions; however, that is most often just taken on a case-by-case basis, without a specific rigorous criterion that applies universally.

Comment: Thank you so much, but my problem is this. A free system, I mean an unforced system is forming a problem of initial conditions which its solutions as far as I know, are standing waves with natural frequencies of the given system. It means that the wave in the above system will not be rotating. For a non-standing wave, one needs an external force. (lets talk about transverse waves as shown above. If a force will be coupled to an arbitrary point on the circle, it will initially produce from both sides two identical traveling waves with opposite phase velocities which will become a standing wave.

Comment: No, that's not true. Depending on the initial condition, the ring system shown will evolve equally well as a travelling or a standing wave, even when unforced. There is absolutely no need for an external force to make travelling waves.